# Randomize characters in loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to randomize the answers in my for loop. My current code only prints: AAA,BBB,CCC.

```
while True:
    for i in range(65,91):
        answer = chr(i) + chr(i) + chr(i)
        print(answer)
```

How can I randomly return every single possible combination like AXY,BMK, etc.

Is this possible with the random module or do I need to use something else?

Comment: Hey there! Put answer = chr(i) + chr(i + 1) + chr(i +2). Hope I helped and happy coding!

Comment: Your answer is working however because of the for loop it only returns items 26 times because of the 65,91 range. How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import string
import random
char_big = string.ascii_uppercase

while True:
    print(''.join(random.choice(char_big) for _ in range(3)))
```

By thanks of @JiříBaum, if this is important for you to prevent from attack you can use `SystemRandom` from `secrets` like below:

```py
import string
import secrets
char_big = string.ascii_uppercase

while True:
    print(''.join(secrets.choice(char_big) for _ in range(3)))
```

Or:

```py
import string
import secrets
char_big = string.ascii_uppercase

while True:
    print(
        ''.join(char_big[secrets.SystemRandom().randrange(0, 26)] \
                for _ in range(3)
               )
    )
```

Comment: Remember to use `secrets` rather than `random` if there may be an adversary involved? The function name is the same...

Comment: @JiříBaum thanks a lot, you are so nice, today I Learn from you. edited answer

Comment: You can use `secrets.choice()`; then it's the same as the code using `random`

Comment: @JiříBaum thanks a lot again, edited answer